# How do I download zip file in C#?

Tags: c#, http, get, download

I use HTTP GET that downloads a zip file in a browser, something like  https://example.com/up/DBID/a/rRID/eFID/vVID (not the exact url)

Now, when I try to do the same download in C# code(same GET method as above) for a desktop application, the zip file downloaded is not a valid archive file. When I opened this file in notepad, it was some HTML page.

I think I'm not setting some header correctly. I looked around for examples. I'd found several wrt uploads, but did not see anything for downloads.

Code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/zip";
try
{
    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.Default))
    {
        StreamWriter oWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Downloads\1.zip");
        oWriter.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
        oWriter.Close();
    }
    res.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

Comment: This is an unguessable 'it doesn't work' question.  Post code, document what you see when you open the file in a hex viewer.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's mainly because you use a `StreamWriter : TextWriter`  to handle a binary Zip file.  A StreamWriter expects text and will apply an Encoding. And even the simple ASCII Encoder might try to 'fix' what it thinks are invalid line-endings.

You can replace all your code with:

```
  using (var client = new WebClient())
  {
    client.DownloadFile("http://something",  @"D:\Downloads\1.zip");
  }
```

[Note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks) that for new code you should look at HttpClient instead of WebClient.
And then don't use `using( ) { }`

Comment: Oh yes, I can see the same problem in there.

Comment: +1 beat me - @Al: I tested this with a zip file and it works just fine, are you sure the file itself is not corrupted already?

Comment: WebClient also created the same type of zip file.

Comment: @Merrin, if you mean "the same faulty Zip file" then you need to give (a lot) more information.

Comment: I think the issue I'm facing is authentication to the service. And then I could probably use the webclient to download the file.

Comment: @Merrin did you sort this out as i am having the same HTML zip problem?

Comment: @AshleyStaggs Yes, for me I was not authenticated when I attempted to download.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Oh my dear god, this answer just saved me **so** much time. Many thanks to you and Google who brought me here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Hi, I am trying to post a zip file from my app (Android is the client) to a IIS server (using C#.net for server side code). But my saved zip file at the server side on opening says it's an corrupted archive. Any pointers of what's wrong? I suspect that the header's are written too but AFAIK I don't think that the `HTTP` POST method from my client app is sending any header(s) just a zip file instead. :|

Comment: @codebreaker - SO is not a forum, if you can't find an exiting answer then post a new question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Please see [my ques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642246/saved-zip-file-gets-corrupted-from-an-android-app-to-an-iis-server). Thanks :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman thanks buddy. you saved my life. its working fine :)

Comment: How to run it if proxy authentication is required?

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments. Search for it and post a new Question if necessary.

Answer (score 8):

You could just use [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) for a 2-liner:

```
using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
   wc.DownloadFile(url, @"D:\Downloads\1.zip");
}
```

Comment: Short and simple. I like that kind of programming. +1 for you

Comment: @anvarbekraupov: I am using a `using` statement - look harder

Comment: @BrokenGlass, replaced my downgrade with +1, apologies!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use System.Net.Http.HttpClient

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(downloadURL))
        {
             using(var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
             {
                  using(Stream zip = FileManager.OpenWrite(ZIP_PATH))
                  {
                       stream.CopyTo(zip);
                  }
             }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Ruben's answer which uses [HttpClient instead of WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient), you can add as an extension method like this:

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static class Extensions
{
    public static async Task DownloadFile (this HttpClient client, string address, string fileName) {
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(address))
        using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
        using (var file = File.OpenWrite(fileName)) {
            stream.CopyTo(file);
        }
    }
}
```

And then use like this:

```cs
var archivePath = "https://api.github.com/repos/microsoft/winget-pkgs/zipball/";
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    await httpClient.DownloadFile(archivePath, "./repo.zip");
}
```