# Saved ZIP File gets Corrupted (from an Android App to an IIS Server)

Tags: c#, java, android, asp.net, http

After [trying to send an XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620007/saving-a-file-posted-using-http-post) file over from my client side app (on Android) to server side(IIS 7). I wasn't getting the XML file's filename but just the content allright. 
Now I realized that simply transferring the bare XML file will be too much heavy (after when I get to sync nearly all of my app's data to the server).


- Now I am in pursuit of sending a zipped file from my client app to the server side. 
- The XML file gets zipped perfectly reducing its size in less than half of its original size. File is being sent using `HTTP POST` method directly using `FileEntity` and **not** using `MultiPart`(Can that be a problem).
**Update 2:**  Added my Own answer (works better :D).
**Update:**  Added Client side code.
**Problem:** 
- The zip file gets saved at the server side but when I opened it winrar/7zip gave me an error saying `unexpected end of archive.`.
 
I referred to a [nearly similar problem](http://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/httpwebresponse-save-zip-file-locally-but-file-is-corrupted-when-unzipped-502499.html) but I have a lower hand on `.NET` development that too in `C#` :( So couldn't really make use of the exact code (missing, non-initialized variables etc.). Also, the thread is like 4 years old and I have really low hope that anyone will respond in there.

**My Existing Server side code:**

```
string fileName = "D:\\newZIPfile.zip";
        Stream myStream = Request.InputStream;
        byte[] message = new byte[myStream.Length];
        myStream.Read(message, 0, (int)myStream.Length);
        string data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                writer.Write(data);
            }
        }
```

**My Client Side Code:**

```
 File file2send = new File(newzipfile);

                String urlString = "http://192.168.1.189/prodataupload/Default.aspx";       // FOR TEST
                HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                int some_reasonable_timeout = (int) (30 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS);

                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, some_reasonable_timeout);

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);

                //System.out.println("SYNC'ing USING METHOD: " + post.getMethod().toString());
             try {
                   //OLD FILE-ENTITY MECHANISM >
                    FileEntity fEntity = new FileEntity(file2send, "application/zip");

                    //NEW (v1.5) INPUTSTREAM-ENTITY MECHANISM >
                    //InputStreamEntity fEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(newzipfile), -1);
                   // fEntity.setContentType("application/zip");
                    post.setEntity(fEntity);

                    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    resEntity = response.getEntity();
                    res_code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();            
                    final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
                    if (resEntity != null) {        
                        Log.i("RESPONSE",response_str);
            //...
```

How can I fix this problem? :(

Comment: whats the os of the server? i have similar issues on win2k3 server. usually coded access still works. try sending the file to your win7 or whatever pc (from the server) and look if its still broken.

Comment: @efkah ..posting the answer in a min :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would tell the problem is due the conversion of the ZIP File (which is binary) in your code to a UTF-8 stream.

Try replacing the server side code to the following:

```
string fileName = "D:\\newZIPfile.zip";

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
    int read;
    while ((read = Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        fs.Write (buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```

This will write the input stream as received to the ZIP file.

To receive the client ZIP-Filename as well, one possibly way would be to change the line

```
String urlString = "http://192.168.1.189/prodataupload/Default.aspx";
```

to something like:

```
String urlString = "http://192.168.1.189/prodataupload/Default.aspx?CLIENTFILENAME=" + 
    urlEncodedFilename;
```

So you can access the parameter by use of the `Request.Params` property.

**Warning**: Do not trust the filename as sent by the client (someone could manipulate it!). Do a strict sanitation/validation on the parameter!

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer. :) But please do see my answer below. Can you tell me what possibly could go wrong with my answer? :|

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell both answers are (more or less) identical. Beside the fact that my answer could possibly yield a bug. It is not safe to assume stream.read reads the whole stream in a single call (I will edit it). Beside that issue I would prefer my solution as it is more compact and easier to read/maintain.

Comment: Is there any way I can read the File name of the zip file? like if I pass it in the header..? Actually I did passed it in the header from my client app and at the time of reading it from `Request.Params` the server side code is not able to fetch it. Always returns null.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet I posted to make it more efficient. It copies the network stream in max. 32K chunks to the file output. `Request.Params` keeps null as header information is not part of the property.

Comment: Thanks it works briliant now! Also, I have updated my client side code heavily so the filename sent is dynamic and will be validated at the server side :) Secondly, setting the buffer was an important thingy you got right there! :)

Comment: Can you please see my updated answer's code below. I have inserted an if/else block checking the request's length. Now I will take it as better in further processing the request (`POST` data) if it's not less than 32K ?

Answer (score 0):

So this problem has been bugging a lot of people across many forums/threads I have gone through till now.

Here's what I did:

- Change the client side to have `binary/octet-stream` content type.

 - change the server side code to:
**UPDATED:**

```
if(Request.InputStream.Length < 32768) {
        Request.ContentType = "binary/octet-stream";
        Stream myStream = Request.InputStream;
        string fName = Request.Params["CLIENTFILENAME"];
        //string fName = Request.Params.GetValues("zipFileName");

        int iContentLengthCounter = 0;
        int maxlength = (int) myStream.Length;
        byte[] bFileWriteData = new byte[maxlength];
        string fileName = "D:\\"+ fName +".zip";

        //FileStream oFileStream = new FileStream();

        while (iContentLengthCounter < maxlength)
       {
           iContentLengthCounter += Request.InputStream.Read(bFileWriteData, iContentLengthCounter, (maxlength - iContentLengthCounter));
       }
        System.IO.FileStream oFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
       oFileStream.Write(bFileWriteData, 0, bFileWriteData.Length);

        oFileStream.Close();
       Request.InputStream.Close();
    }
    else
    {
    }
```

Basically..I have not been picking up data acc. to its length.
(answer requires editing..to be done later)

Comment: @efkah Yes, both mine and GeneSys works as expected! (now am just trying to improve it further..features to be added). :)