# Deciding between HttpClient and WebClient

Tags: c#, .net, rest, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

Our web application is running in .NET Framework 4.0. The UI calls the controller methods through Ajax calls.

We need to consume the REST service from our vendor.   I am evaluating the best way to call the REST service in .NET 4.0.  The REST service requires a basic authentication scheme and it can return data in both XML and JSON.

There isn't any requirement for uploading/downloading huge data and I don't see anything in future. I took a look at few open source code projects for REST consumption and didn't find any value in those to justify additional dependency in the project. I started to evaluate `WebClient` and `HttpClient`. I downloaded HttpClient for .NET 4.0 from [NuGet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NuGet).

I searched for differences between `WebClient` and `HttpClient` and [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20140217233914/http://blogs.k10world.com/technology/webclient-httpclient-consume-http-requests/) mentioned that single HttpClient can handle concurrent calls and it can reuse resolved DNS, cookie configuration and authentication. I am yet to see practical values that we may gain due to the differences.

I did a quick performance test to find how `WebClient` (synchronous calls), `HttpClient` (synchronous and asynchronous) perform. And here are the results:

I am using the same `HttpClient` instance for all the requests (minimum - maximum).

> WebClient sync: 8 ms - 167 ms 
> HttpClient sync: 3 ms - 7228 ms 
> HttpClient async: 985 - 10405 ms

Using a new `HttpClient` for each request (minimum - maximum):

> WebClient sync: 4 ms - 297 ms 
> HttpClient sync: 3 ms - 7953 ms 
> HttpClient async: 1027 - 10834 ms

### Code

```cs
public class AHNData
{
    public int i;
    public string str;
}

public class Program
{
    public static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    private static readonly string _url = "http://localhost:9000/api/values/";

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       #region "Trace"
       Trace.Listeners.Clear();

       TextWriterTraceListener twtl = new TextWriterTraceListener(
           "C:\\Temp\\REST_Test.txt");
       twtl.Name = "TextLogger";
       twtl.TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.ThreadId | TraceOptions.DateTime;

       ConsoleTraceListener ctl = new ConsoleTraceListener(false);
       ctl.TraceOutputOptions = TraceOptions.DateTime;

       Trace.Listeners.Add(twtl);
       Trace.Listeners.Add(ctl);
       Trace.AutoFlush = true;
       #endregion

       int batchSize = 1000;

       ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
       parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = batchSize;

       ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000000;

       Parallel.For(0, batchSize, parallelOptions,
           j =>
           {
               Stopwatch sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
               GetDataFromHttpClientAsync<List<AHNData>>(sw1);
           });
       Parallel.For(0, batchSize, parallelOptions,
            j =>
            {
                Stopwatch sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                GetDataFromHttpClientSync<List<AHNData>>(sw1);
            });
       Parallel.For(0, batchSize, parallelOptions,
            j =>
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                   Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                   byte[] arr = client.DownloadData(_url);
                   sw.Stop();

                   Trace.WriteLine("WebClient Sync " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                }
           });

           Console.Read();
        }

        public static T GetDataFromWebClient<T>()
        {
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.BaseAddress = _url;
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(
                    webClient.DownloadString(_url));
            }
        }

        public static void GetDataFromHttpClientSync<T>(Stopwatch sw)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var response = httpClient.GetAsync(_url).Result;
            var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(
                response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            sw.Stop();

            Trace.WriteLine("HttpClient Sync " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        public static void GetDataFromHttpClientAsync<T>(Stopwatch sw)
        {
           HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
           var response = httpClient.GetAsync(_url).ContinueWith(
              (a) => {
                 JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(
                    a.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
                 sw.Stop();
                 Trace.WriteLine("HttpClient Async " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
              }, TaskContinuationOptions.None);
        }
    }
}
```

### My Questions

1. The REST calls return in 3-4 seconds which is acceptable.  Calls to REST
   service are initiated in the controller methods which gets invoked from
   Ajax calls. To begin with, the calls runs in a different thread and doesn't block the UI. So, can I just stick with synchronous calls?
2. The above code was run in my localbox. In a production setup, DNS and proxy
   lookup will be involved. Is there an advantage of using `HttpClient` over `WebClient`?
3. Is `HttpClient` concurrency better than `WebClient`? From the test results, I see `WebClient` synchronous calls perform better.
4. Will `HttpClient` be a better design choice if we upgrade to .NET 4.5? Performance is the key design factor.

Comment: Your test is unfair to `GetDataFromHttpClientAsync` because it runs first, the other invocations get to benefit of potentially having cahed data (be it on the local machine or any transparent proxy between you and the destination) and will be faster. Also, under the right conditions `var response = httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:9000/api/values/").Result;` can result in a deadlock due to you exhausting threadpool threads. You should never block on a activity that depends on the thread pool in ThreadPool threads , you should `await` instead so it returns the thread back in to the pool.

Comment: HttpClient with Web API Client is fantastic for a JSON/XML REST client.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain  - Thanks for your reply. As all the test  calls run in Parallel.Foreach, there is no guarantee which one would have run first. Also, had the first call to the service was from GetDataFromHttpClientAsync , all subsequent calls from GetDataFromHttpClientAsync should have benefited from cache and run faster. I didn't see that in the result. Rgd await, we are still using 4.0. I  agree with you that HttpClient in sync fashion would lead to deadlock and I am ruling that option out of my design consideration.

Comment: @CoryNelson Can you please elaborate why HttpClient with Web API Client is fantastic for a JSON/XML REST client ?

Comment: From the code you posted all of the test calls are in a `Parallel.For` but you still run each ***type*** of test sequentially. The way `Parallel` works it starts with one thread and then ramps up up to `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, ***it does not start at the max***. So if the first call on the single thread took `800ms` to complete, the 999 operations after it may only take `.1ms` (reading from the chached result). Then the cached result is also used for the other two tests (who also start at one thread) however their first test only takes `.1ms` because the result was ready...

Comment: Swap the order of your best performer `WebClient Sync` with your worst performer `HttpClient Async` and please tell me what results you get.

Comment: I agree about the sequential order of the Parallel.For. I changed the order of tests to                                                   1.WebClientSync 2.HttpClientsync 3. HttpClientAsync. here's the result  WebClient Sync 3ms - 79 ms
        HttpClientSync 3 ms - 7927ms
        HttpClientASync 380 ms - 1694 ms

Comment: HttpClientAsync is still a slow performer because of the overhead it has to incur for creating new tasks.

Comment: Here are few words on the difference between HttpClient and WebClient: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/11/httpclient-is-here.aspx

Comment: You are using HttpClient wrong way, you are waiting on `.Result` which is why HttpClient is slower, waiting for result is not same as async call.

Comment: Has anyone done a proper test on this to see if the performance discrepancy can be explained? Also, [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) now seems to have async methods as well.

Comment: @crush There is no `WebClient` in `.Net Core` but `HttpClient` is.

Comment: Note the warning about **HttpClient** at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.-ctor?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Net.Http.HttpClient.%2523ctor)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks concerning proper use of HttpClient. This warning is true for both .NET Framework and .NET Core.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netcore-2.2#remarks recommends using `HttpClient` for new development instead of `WebClient`. This is true for both .NET Framework and .NET Core.

Comment: The question is moot since at least 2018 because even .NET Framework's HttpWebRequest and by extension WebClient [actually use HttpClient](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0ba7aa8026280ee3571179cc06431baf1dfaaac/src/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs#L1005) WebClient and HttpWebRequest are just compatibility wrappers over HttpClient for some years, with the .NET Framework version having a socket exhaustion bug that was fixed in .NET Core

Comment: A [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient/27737601#27737601) on this question is being discussed [on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418595/were-there-options-other-than-deleting-this-answer)

Answer (score 98):

HttpClient is the newer of the APIs and it has the benefits of

- has a good asynchronous programming model
- being worked on by Henrik F Nielson who is basically one of the inventors of HTTP, and he designed the API so it is easy for you to follow the HTTP standard, e.g. generating standards-compliant headers
- is in the .NET framework 4.5, so it has some guaranteed level of support for the forseeable future
- also has the [xcopy](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)able/portable-framework version of the library if you want to use it on other platforms - .NET 4.0, [Windows Phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone), etc.

If you are writing a web service which is making REST calls to other web services, you should want to be using an asynchronous programming model for all your REST calls, so that you don't hit thread starvation. You probably also want to use the newest C# compiler which has [async/await](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Async/await) support.

Note: It isn't more performant, AFAIK. It's probably somewhat similarly performant if you create a fair test.

Comment: If it had a way to switch proxy it would be insane

Comment: While this is an old question, it came up on my search, so I thought I'd point out that Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-5.0) for `WebClient` in .NET 5 states, "We don't recommend that you use the `WebClient` class for new development. Instead, use the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class."

Answer (score 13):

#### HttpClientFactory

It's important to evaluate the different ways you can create an HttpClient, and part of that is understanding HttpClientFactory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

This is not a direct answer I know - but you're better off starting here than ending up with `new HttpClient(...)` everywhere.

Comment: It's worth stressing that even HttpWebRequest in .NET Framework and by extension WebClient [use HttpClient](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0ba7aa8026280ee3571179cc06431baf1dfaaac/src/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs#L1005) since at least 2018, so the question is essentially moot

Answer (score 13):

When it comes *to ASP.NET apps* I still prefer `WebClient` over `HttpClient` because:

1. The modern implementation comes with async/awaitable task-based methods
2. Has smaller memory footprint and 2-5 times faster (other answers already mention that)
3. It's suggested to "*reuse a single
   instance of HttpClient for the lifetime of your application*". But
   ASP.NET has no "lifetime of application", only lifetime of a request. The current guidance for ASP.NET 5 is to use `HttpClientFactory`, but it can only be used via dependency injection. Some people want a simpler solution.
4. Most importantly, if you're using one singleton instance of HttpClient through the lifetime of the app like MS suggests - **it has known issues**. For example the DNS caching issue - HttpClient simply ignores the TTL and caches DNS "forever". There are workarounds, however. If you'd like to learn more about the issues and confusion with HttpClient just read [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28385#issuecomment-853766480) at Microsoft GitHub.

Comment: Given how .NET Old has been replaced by .NET Core, have you run your benchmarks with .NET Core? By now HttpWebRequest is a wrapper over HttpClient, so WebClient is essentially a legacy adapter for WebClient

Comment: `only lifetime of a request.` that's wrong. Using DI containers to provide singleton or scoped objects is available in the older ASP.NET stacks too, only harder to use.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, but you still do not control lifetime of the application. And average "Joe the programmer" won't bother creating static/singleton vars to cache the HttpClient anyway.

Comment: The lifetime of the application doesn't matter, only the injected HttpClient's - or rather, the HttpClientHandler's. Which is something easily doable for all applications. And HttpWebRequest *does* use a cached HttpClientHandler if available. You should rerun your benchmarks. If your results say that the wrapper over a class is faster or uses less memory than the class itself, something's wrong

Comment: Also this ".NET Old has been replaced by .NET Core" - it hasn't *replaced* it yet, .NET Framework is still supported and will be for another 10 years at the very least (basically as long as it's part of Windows). BUt i should've probably indicated that my answer is for .NET Framework, not Core

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos by the way looking at the source code for `HttpWebRequest`, I see that it creates a new `HttpCLientHandler` https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0ba7aa8026280ee3571179cc06431baf1dfaaac/src/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs#L1103
Can you point me otherwise?

Comment: And two lines lower, that's used in an HttpClient. That's the .NET Old repo though. In .NET Core the client and handler are readonly fields since August 2019 and cached since October 2019. The [curent code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs#L77) is `private static volatile HttpClient? s_cachedHttpClient;`

Comment: As for .NET Old still being supported, it's "supported" in the same way Silverlight was "supported" in the last 10 years. No new development, patches only and after some time, only if you pay. The link you posted shows that - there were no fixes to HttpWebRequest in the last 3 years. `HttpClient` is disposed when it shouldn't. And even though `SendRequest` is async, there's no `GetResponseAsync`. The APM methods are wrappers over the `SendRequest` task

Comment: Which means using HttpWebRequest in .NET Framework [suffers from socket exhaustion](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). This shows what "support" means. Microsoft know about it but isn't fixing it. If you paid to fix the problem, you'd get a binary just for you

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos agreed on the .NET Core vs Framework point, even though the product is immature (personal opinion from someone who just ported a huge app, and should probably be ignored). HUGE THANKS for the source code link. Also, we are closely monitoring thread starvation on production using `dotnet-counters` and I confirm that WebCLient is not starving threads in .NET Core (if used async-ly)

Comment: what is asp.net 5? you mean .net 5?

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, I am not an authority on WebClient vs. HttpClient, specifically.  Secondly, from your comments above, it seems to suggest that WebClient is synchronous  *only* whereas HttpClient is both.

> I did a quick performance test to find how WebClient (synchronous calls), HttpClient (synchronous and asynchronous) perform. And here are the results.

I see that as a huge difference when thinking for future, i.e., long running processes, responsive GUI, etc. (add to the benefit you suggest by .NET framework 4.5 - which in my actual experience is hugely faster on [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services)).

Comment: [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) does seem to have async capabilities in the latest .NET versions. I'd like to know why it seems to be outperforming HttpClient on such a massive scale.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4988325/1662973, it seems to be the same, other than the fact that one is an abstraction of the other.  Maybe, it depends on how the objects are used / loaded.  The minimum time does support the statement that webclient is in fact an abstraction of HttpClient, so there is a millisecond worth of overhead.   The framework could be being "sneaky" in how it is really pooling or disposing of webclient.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you could think about the problem in a different way. `WebClient` and `HttpClient` are essentially different implementations of the same thing. What I recommend is implementing the [Dependency Injection pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) with an [IoC Container](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx) throughout your application. You should construct a client interface with a higher level of abstraction than the low level HTTP transfer. You can write concrete classes that use both `WebClient` and `HttpClient`, and then use the IoC container to inject the implementation via config.

What this would allow you to do would be to switch between `HttpClient` and `WebClient` easily so that you are able to objectively test in the production environment.

So questions like:

> Will HttpClient be a better design choice if we upgrade to .Net 4.5?

Can actually be objectively answered by switching between the two client implementations using the IoC container. Here is an example interface that you might depend on that doesn't include any details about `HttpClient` or `WebClient`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Dependency Injection abstraction for rest clients. 
/// </summary>
public interface IClient
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adapter for serialization/deserialization of http body data
    /// </summary>
    ISerializationAdapter SerializationAdapter { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sends a strongly typed request to the server and waits for a strongly typed response
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResponseBody">The expected type of the response body</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TRequestBody">The type of the request body if specified</typeparam>
    /// <param name="request">The request that will be translated to a http request</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    Task<Response<TResponseBody>> SendAsync<TResponseBody, TRequestBody>(Request<TRequestBody> request);

    /// <summary>
    /// Default headers to be sent with http requests
    /// </summary>
    IHeadersCollection DefaultRequestHeaders { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Default timeout for http requests
    /// </summary>
    TimeSpan Timeout { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Base Uri for the client. Any resources specified on requests will be relative to this.
    /// </summary>
    Uri BaseUri { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Name of the client
    /// </summary>
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Request<TRequestBody>
{
    #region Public Properties
    public IHeadersCollection Headers { get; }
    public Uri Resource { get; set; }
    public HttpRequestMethod HttpRequestMethod { get; set; }
    public TRequestBody Body { get; set; }
    public CancellationToken CancellationToken { get; set; }
    public string CustomHttpRequestMethod { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public Request(Uri resource,
        TRequestBody body,
        IHeadersCollection headers,
        HttpRequestMethod httpRequestMethod,
        IClient client,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Body = body;
        Headers = headers;
        Resource = resource;
        HttpRequestMethod = httpRequestMethod;
        CancellationToken = cancellationToken;

        if (Headers == null) Headers = new RequestHeadersCollection();

        var defaultRequestHeaders = client?.DefaultRequestHeaders;
        if (defaultRequestHeaders == null) return;

        foreach (var kvp in defaultRequestHeaders)
        {
            Headers.Add(kvp);
        }
    }
}

public abstract class Response<TResponseBody> : Response
{
    #region Public Properties
    public virtual TResponseBody Body { get; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// Only used for mocking or other inheritance
    /// </summary>
    protected Response() : base()
    {
    }

    protected Response(
    IHeadersCollection headersCollection,
    int statusCode,
    HttpRequestMethod httpRequestMethod,
    byte[] responseData,
    TResponseBody body,
    Uri requestUri
    ) : base(
        headersCollection,
        statusCode,
        httpRequestMethod,
        responseData,
        requestUri)
    {
        Body = body;
    }

    public static implicit operator TResponseBody(Response<TResponseBody> readResult)
    {
        return readResult.Body;
    }
    #endregion
}

public abstract class Response
{
    #region Fields
    private readonly byte[] _responseData;
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties
    public virtual int StatusCode { get; }
    public virtual IHeadersCollection Headers { get; }
    public virtual HttpRequestMethod HttpRequestMethod { get; }
    public abstract bool IsSuccess { get; }
    public virtual Uri RequestUri { get; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    /// <summary>
    /// Only used for mocking or other inheritance
    /// </summary>
    protected Response()
    {
    }

    protected Response
    (
    IHeadersCollection headersCollection,
    int statusCode,
    HttpRequestMethod httpRequestMethod,
    byte[] responseData,
    Uri requestUri
    )
    {
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Headers = headersCollection;
        HttpRequestMethod = httpRequestMethod;
        RequestUri = requestUri;
        _responseData = responseData;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public virtual byte[] GetResponseData()
    {
        return _responseData;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

[Full code](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/RestClient.Net/blob/1deaa083f3f97ddd284478e2b19c71a844105fd8/RestClient.Net.Abstractions/IClient.cs#L9)

[HttpClient Implementation](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/RestClient.Net/blob/1deaa083f3f97ddd284478e2b19c71a844105fd8/RestClient.Net/Client.cs#L22)

You can use `Task.Run` to make `WebClient` run asynchronously in its implementation.

Dependency Injection, when done well helps alleviate the problem of having to make low level decisions upfront. Ultimately, the only way to know the true answer is try both in a live environment and see which one works the best. It's quite possible that `WebClient` may work better for some customers, and `HttpClient` may work better for others. This is why abstraction is important. It means that code can quickly be swapped in, or changed with configuration without changing the fundamental design of the app.

BTW: there are numerous other reasons that you should use an abstraction instead of directly calling one of these low-level APIs. One huge one being unit-testability.

Comment: For this example, why use an abstract as opposed to an interface?
(ignoring default implementations)

Is it purely for the purposes of the GetResponseData() definition?

Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: I'm curious why you chose to use an Abstract here, as opposed to an interface with your "Response" objects (generic and non-generic)

Comment: WebClient uses HttpClient indirectly, because [HttpWebRequest uses HttpClient internally](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0ba7aa8026280ee3571179cc06431baf1dfaaac/src/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs#L1103) even in .NET Framework, since at least 2018. Both WebClient and HttpWebRrequest  are just obsolete compatibility wrappers at this point. WebClient *does* have proper async methods so it doesn't need `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 3):

I have benchmarked between HttpClient, WebClient, and HttpWebResponse, and then called the REST Web API.

And the results:

#### Call REST Web API Benchmark

```
---------------------Stage 1  ---- 10 Request

{00:00:17.2232544} ====>HttpClinet
{00:00:04.3108986} ====>WebRequest
{00:00:04.5436889} ====>WebClient

---------------------Stage 1  ---- 10 Request--Small Size
{00:00:17.2232544}====>HttpClinet
{00:00:04.3108986}====>WebRequest
{00:00:04.5436889}====>WebClient

---------------------Stage 3  ---- 10 sync Request--Small Size
{00:00:15.3047502}====>HttpClinet
{00:00:03.5505249}====>WebRequest
{00:00:04.0761359}====>WebClient

---------------------Stage 4  ---- 100 sync Request--Small Size
{00:03:23.6268086}====>HttpClinet
{00:00:47.1406632}====>WebRequest
{00:01:01.2319499}====>WebClient

---------------------Stage 5  ---- 10 sync Request--Max Size

{00:00:58.1804677}====>HttpClinet
{00:00:58.0710444}====>WebRequest
{00:00:38.4170938}====>WebClient

---------------------Stage 6  ---- 10 sync Request--Max Size

{00:01:04.9964278}====>HttpClinet
{00:00:59.1429764}====>WebRequest
{00:00:32.0584836}====>WebClient
```

#### WebClient Is faster

```
var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

stopWatch.Start();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    CallGetHttpClient();
    CallPostHttpClient();
}

stopWatch.Stop();

var httpClientValue = stopWatch.Elapsed;

stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

stopWatch.Start();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    CallGetWebRequest();
    CallPostWebRequest();
}

stopWatch.Stop();

var webRequesttValue = stopWatch.Elapsed;

stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

stopWatch.Start();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    CallGetWebClient();
    CallPostWebClient();
}

stopWatch.Stop();

var webClientValue = stopWatch.Elapsed;

//-------------------------Functions

private void CallPostHttpClient()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44354/api/test/");
    var responseTask = httpClient.PostAsync("PostJson", null);
    responseTask.Wait();

    var result = responseTask.Result;
    var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}

private void CallGetHttpClient()
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44354/api/test/");
    var responseTask = httpClient.GetAsync("getjson");
    responseTask.Wait();

    var result = responseTask.Result;
    var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}

private string CallGetWebRequest()
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44354/api/test/getjson");

    request.Method = "GET";
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

    var content = string.Empty;

    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                content = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    return content;
}

private string CallPostWebRequest()
{
    var apiUrl = "https://localhost:44354/api/test/PostJson";

    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(apiUrl));
    httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpRequest.ContentLength = 0;

    using (var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var json = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
            return json;
        }
    }
    return "";
}

private string CallGetWebClient()
{
    string apiUrl = "https://localhost:44354/api/test/getjson";

    var client = new WebClient();

    client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";

    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    var json = client.DownloadString(apiUrl);

    return json;
}

private string CallPostWebClient()
{
    string apiUrl = "https://localhost:44354/api/test/PostJson";

    var client = new WebClient();

    client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";

    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

    var json = client.UploadString(apiUrl, "");

    return json;
}
```

Comment: See Gabriel's comment above. In short, HttpClient is much faster if you create one instance of HttpClient and reuse it.

Comment: Besides, HttpWebRequest calls HttpClient in .NET Core. Which is the only platform going forward

Comment: In fact, HttpWebRequests uses HttpClient even in .NET Framework, although it has bugs. That `GetResponse()` [calls `HttpClient` underneath](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0ba7aa8026280ee3571179cc06431baf1dfaaac/src/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs#L1103)  and [blocks](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e0ba7aa8026280ee3571179cc06431baf1dfaaac/src/System.Net.Requests/src/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs#L1005) with `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`