# How to specify message body in a WebClient?

Tags: c#, azure, authorization, webclient, token

In the console, I follow up a call the site I'm on is is making and I can see the address (*some.site.com/gettoken*), message header and something that FF calls *Message Body*. It's in the latter that I can see the credentials that I've entered on the site that are being sent.

So, I've got the URL and the message body. Then, I've tried to implement the behavior using C# for my Azure service layer like so.

```
String url = @"https://some.site.com/gettoken";
String credentials = "username=super&password=secret";
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
  String output = client.UploadString(url, credentials);
  result = output;
}
```

However, I get error 400 - bad result. What did I miss?

I've googled for [some stuff](https://www.google.se/search?newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=how+to+specify+%22message+body%22+with+webclient+in+c%23&oq=how+to+specify+%22message+body%22+with+webclient+in+c%23&gs_l=hp.3...1766.16798.0.17267.59.56.1.1.1.1.235.6256.15j35j3.53.0.msedrc...0...1c.1.58.hp..22.37.3951.0.HXF6Ssd-Qz0) but the only remotely relevant hits are talking about the upload methods, which I've used. Am I barking up the wrong tree entirely or just missing something tiny? [Some people](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5401597/1525840) seem to get it to work but they're not tokenizing around. And I'm not certain enough to determine whether it's of relevance or not.

Comment: Can you use [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)? Your code would be `client.PostAsync(url, new HttpStringContent(credentials));` then. Or `new FormUrlEncodedContent` if you don't manually build the string. I'm not entirely certain how the `WebClient` does this.

Comment: I've been suggested to use *WebClient* because it's smoother than *HttpWebRequest* but a [internet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23949674/1525840) says that *HttpClient* is even newer/better, so sure, why not. However, the asynchronous part is worrying me a bit. I need to obtain the token **before** doing anything else. Sync seems to be the safest way, doesn't it?

Comment: If you just `await` the call you will be fine; execution of the method won't continue until the call is finished.

Comment: Hmm... Seems that I can't find *Http**String**Content*. Only *HttpContent* and it's got an empty constructor... I did reference the ass for *HttpClient*, of course. What more could that be? Did you typo'ed? *Http.StringContent*? Also, I can only find *Wait* no *Await* in the *Task* object returned. Is that it?

Comment: it's `System.net.http.StringContent`. As to the wait/await: that's part of the *TPL*, more on that here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: OK, two things. (a) Post this as a reply because it seems to be the most concurrent usage of the libraries and seems to be nicely compact and pro. (b) The software doesn't crash and burn anymore so I'm guessing you got me going - but where is the token?! I can't find anything in the *Task* object...

Comment: Darn... I'm not quite there yet. I get this when I *ToString* the *Result* property: StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:\u000d\u000a{\u000d\u000a  Transfer-Encoding: chunked\u000d\u000a  Connection: keep-alive\u000d\u000a  Vary: Accept-Encoding\u000d\u000a  X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN\u000d\u000a  Date: Wed, 12 Nov 2014 18:34:28 GMT\u000d\u000a  Set-Cookie: lang=\"en\";Max-Age=31622400;expires=Fri, 13-Nov-2015 18:34:27 GMT;Path=\/;Version=\"1\"  Server: nginx\/1.4.1 Server: (Ubuntu)  Content-Type: text\/html; charset=utf-8}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as a summary of what has been discussed in the comments: you can use [the more modern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/need-help-deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient) `HttpClient` instead.

Note that this is the [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) and not [`Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.web.http.httpclient).

An example implementation could look like this:

```
public async Task<string> SendCredentials()
{
    string url = @"https://some.site.com/gettoken";
    string credentials = "username=super&password=secret";
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(credentials));
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

You might also be interested in [`System.Net.Http.FormUrlEncodedContent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent(v=vs.110).aspx) which allows you to pass in the parameters and their values so you don't have to construct the `credentials` value yourself.

[More information on async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).