# Obtaining a token for authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, httpclient, token

I asked how to set up a call to a service and got [a great info on HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26894270/1525840). However, while **that** question's technically answered, I still get stuck.

In the console, I can see what request my browser send to the service to obtain the token for authorization. However, when I try to mimic the call building the request in my service layer, I get the following error message. The probability of **me** being at fault here is pretty steep. Not sure what to google for, really...

> "StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:\u000d\u000a{\u000d\u000a  Transfer-Encoding: chunked\u000d\u000a  Connection: keep-alive\u000d\u000a  Date: Wed, 12 Nov 2014 21:00:34 GMT\u000d\u000a  Set-Cookie: lang=\"en\";Max-Age=31622400;expires=Fri, 13-Nov-2015 21:00:33 GMT;Path=/;Version=\"1\"\u000d\u000a  Server: nginx/1.4.1\u000d\u000a  Server: (Ubuntu)\u000d\u000a  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\u000d\u000a}"

The call itself looks like this.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
  Task<HttpResponseMessage> message 
    = client.PostAsync(urlToken, new StringContent(credentials));
  message.Wait();
  result = message.Result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: 500 error indicates something went wrong in the service.  Check your web server logs and the event viewer to see if anything was logged there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was posted in the answer that you accepted in your linked post, you need to read the content of the response. Calling ToString() directly on the response is not showing you the actual error.

Change your code to something like:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
  var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(credentials));
  result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Once you can see the actual response message from the server, you should be able to figure out what to do next.

Comment: I don't get the *Content* property from my intellisense. Also, *await* requires the whole method to be async. But I need it to be executed "in sync". That's why I go *message.Wait()*. Am I totally off here?

Comment: You don't see `.Content` because that property exists on `HttpResponseMessage`, not `Task`. You should see it on `message.Result`. As for your question about being totally off, I cannot say. You have presented too little context to know. Having said that, it is generally a bad practice to do what you're doing. See @stephencleary's blog post [on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).