# WebClient vs. HttpClient - Async request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I have this very simple WebApi method:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Foo()
{
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    return Ok("Bar");
}
```

And I have these two methods in a console application that call it:

```
async Task UsingWebClient()
{
    Task<string> task = new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync (new Uri ("http://localhost.fiddler:63710/api/producttype/Foo"));
    Console.WriteLine("WebClient - Before calling wait");
    string result = await task;
    Console.WriteLine("WebClient - After calling wait");
}

async Task UsingHttpClient()
{
    Task<string> task = new HttpClient().GetStringAsync (new Uri ("http://localhost.fiddler:63710/api/producttype/Foo"));
    Console.WriteLine("HttpClient - Before calling wait");
    string result = await task;
    Console.WriteLine("HttpClient - After calling wait");
}
```

And I am calling these methods from LinqPad like this:

```
async Task Main()
{
    await UsingWebClient();
    await UsingHttpClient();
}
```

I was monitoring the traffic using Fiddler and I noticed that:

- when using WebClient the request to the web api is made immediately
  and then execution continues to Console.WriteLine("WebClient - Before
  calling wait");
- when using HttpClient the request to the web api is not made until
  the call to await task;

I'm trying to understand why the request is not made immediately when using HttpClient. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is not a duplicate question. I'm not looking for reasons to choose one option over the other - I'll use HttpClient. I would like to know specifically why the request is created at a later stage when using HttpClient.

Thanks,
David

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help deciding between HttpClient and WebClient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/need-help-deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient)

Comment: HttpClient is newer and probably optimized better for supporting Async Requests.

Comment: just to be sure: how often did you test this and are your really sure that you can really decide what happened when?

Comment: @CarstenKönig I've run those methods quite a few times today and what I've been seeing in Fiddler is pretty predicatable. If I set a breakpoint in the second line of the UsingWebClient method I can clearly see that the request has been sent in Fiddler. If I set a breakpoint in the third line of UsingHttpClient I can see that the request has not been sent and it is only sent after the third line executes.

Comment: CAn you show the code calling `UsingWebClient` and `UsingHttpClient`?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I've edited my question to show the calling code

Comment: If you call `UsingHttpClient` first and then `UsingWebClient`, do those methods behave the same way? Or do you notice that they exchanged  behavior?

Comment: Calling UsingHttpClient first and then UsingWebClient does not result in any changed behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Since both of the requests are async, none of them should delay execution of your *current thread* (significantly).

It is possible, though, that one of them can send the request before the current thread reaches the next line, while the other cannot.

These kinds of timing issues can happen in asynchronous/parallel environments and they're nothing to worry about as long as you don't separate logically successive operations.

Comment: But doesn't the fact that the code using WebClient sends the request to the web api immediately imply that it will get a response quicker and give better performance?

Comment: It may imply that, but it is not neccessarily so. The time they take to initialize might be different, among a bunch of other things as well.

If you want to measure their performance, then do so - the average time between sending the request and getting a response is not very difficult to measure.