# How to use System.Net.WebClient in Visual Studio Code on OS X?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, webclient, system.net

I got a little problem by using the `WebClient` class in `System.Net`
Everything I got is the reference to `System.Net`, which is working. But I cannot find any `WebClient` class.

Can somebody help me or has the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

VS Code on OS X uses .NET core, which does not support WebClient. 
You would need to use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx).

See [Need help deciding between HttpClient and WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20530152/195653) for details.