# HttpClient doesn't redirect even when AllowAutoRedirect = true

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to parse a wikispaces page but I'm not able to get the actual page. I'm not sure if its a HttpClient bug or some missing configuration.

This is my code:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
_httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient
    .GetAsync("http://medivia.wikispaces.com/Monsters");
```

When i run that code I get the StatusCode 302 and get sent to https://session.wikispaces.com/1/auth/auth?authToken=token. I expect the HttpClient to follow a 302 because I have `AllowAutoRedirect = true`.

This is the first time I've encountered this problem. It works fine with Postman and RestClient which is part of RestSharp.

Comment: Why not use `WebClient`?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood it but if you don't want to follow the redirect you could simply set ```handler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;```

Comment: @LeiYang Because `WebClient` is old, horrible and needs to die a nasty, painful death!

Comment: Why is it old? you mean .net framework version?

Comment: @LeiYang http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/need-help-deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient

Comment: im using HttpClient becouse its the standard one for net core... never had any problems before... @giubueno i need to redirect, the problem is that HttpClient might not redirect enough ive even set the MaxRedirect to a absurd number and still didnt fix it.

Comment: Hi @Diego, welcome to StackOverflow! I took the liberty of editing your post to make it easier to understand. Feel free to undo the edits if you feel I have changed the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason the HttpClient isn't redirecting properly is because the site is redirecting you to HTTPS and then back to HTTP. A quick fix is to GET `https://medivia.wikispaces.com/Monsters` instead, which is a better idea anyhow:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("https://medivia.wikispaces.com/Monsters");
// Works fine! :)
```

I was curious why it didn't work the first way, so I dug a little deeper. If you watch the network trace in a browser or a network client, this is what happens:

```
GET http://medivia.wikispaces.com/Monsters
302 https://session.wikispaces.com/1/auth/auth?authToken=token
302 http://medivia.wikispaces.com/Monsters?redirectToken=token
```

That 302 from an encrypted (HTTPS) connection to an unencrypted one is causing the HttpClientHandler to stop automatically following. From what I can tell, this is a security quirk of the [Windows implementation of HttpClientHandler](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClientHandler.Windows.cs), because the [Unix one](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClientHandler.Unix.cs) didn't seem to care about the HTTPS->HTTP redirect in my informal testing.

Comment: Helped me as well, nice find!

Comment: Is there a way to stop this behavior? And have it stick to either http or https?

Comment: @mjwrazor Setting `HttpClientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false` will disable any redirecting behavior.

Comment: Wow, so terrible that this 'hidden feature' exists, and even not consistently cross-platform. The feature might make sense, but at least there should be a configuration option for it on HttpClient.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried a lot of options to resolve WebClient error 302. Any example works fine, but this example works perfect. Let me share my example for the comunity.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("www.google.com");

// Works fine
var resultBytes = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

var writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(strFilePath, 
FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write));
writer.Write(resultBytes);
writer.Close();
```

Comment: While your answer may be a solution for "issues with 302 error on `WebClient`" the question of this thread is already using `HttpClient`.