# How to send data from win forms to web using Json?

Tags: c#

I cannot pass value properly. This code executed successfully but the null value reached to the specified page("http://.............).

```
Product objProduct = new Product();
objProduct.id = "1";
objProduct.name = "Sana";
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objProduct);

var baseAddress = "http://..................";

var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(baseAddress));
http.Accept = "application/json";
http.ContentType = "application/json";
http.Method = "POST";

string parsedContent = json;
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
Byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(parsedContent);

Stream newStream = http.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
newStream.Close();

var response = http.GetResponse();

var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Are you sure that this Json object is valid for that request?

Comment: when i executed my code the json string contains the followinf value

Comment: {"id":"1","name":"Sana","products":null,"success":0}

Comment: Where did you set the `products` property? You simply don't seem to set it anywhere.

Comment: product is a class

Comment: But where do you set it? I see you set `id` and `name`, but not `products`.

Comment: public class Product
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

Comment: json hold the value  {"id":"1","name":"Sana"}

Comment: In a comment you seem to indicate that the response is not what you expect. Why show us the request code then? How do you return a response from the server?

Comment: After execution content variable shows {"products":[{"id":null,"name":null}],"success":1}

Comment: would you please give me a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another simple solution that I use to make request is [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) and your code can be like this

```
  Product objProduct = new Product();
  objProduct.id = "1";
  objProduct.name = "Sana";
  string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objProduct);
  var baseAddress = "http://..................";

  var respond = "";

  //Post request 
  using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
  {
    wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    respond =  wc.UploadString(baseAddress, json);
  }
```

the respond variable here will have the result of API return

Comment: the respond variable hold  {"products":[{"id":null,"name":null}],"success":1}

Comment: during the execution joson variable shows {"id":"1","name":"Sana"}. But after execution the responds hold nul value.i couldnt find the reason

Comment: It 's depend of the return from you services , what is the return statement in your services @Ajisha

Comment: "It 's depend of the return from you services , what is the return statement in your services "  what you mean by service

Comment: Return data from a php server. But i can receive data from that server. That code executed properly.

Comment: would you please give me a solution for my problem

Comment: The UploadString Uploads the specified string to the specified resource, using the POST method,and return  string containing the response sent by the server. so the result is handle by the service @Ajisha

Comment: Is your api service public so I can look at ?? @Ajisha

Comment: that code is working. The problem is in the server side code. so i fix that error. Then both the solutions executed properly..thank you....

Answer (score 1):

Can you use [Microsoft.Net.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/)

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()) 
{
    var objProduct = new Product();
    objProduct.id = "1";
    objProduct.name = "Sana";
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objProduct);
    var content = new StringContent(json);
    var result = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost/product/", content);
    var responseAsString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: What is the deffrent between HttpClient and WebClient ?

Comment: @Muhammad it's a question that it's answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/need-help-deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient/27737601#27737601

Comment: hav you any solution for my problem

Comment: @Ajisha since you could installed the package you should add to the method the `async` keyword.... but I'm thinking that as @PatrickHofman said the answer is not the correct and it does not helps you because you will need to modify the methods to work with asynchronous programming https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you're using .net framework 4 you should not be able to install the package since it works from >= 4.5, Modify your question and add the way you deserialize the response