# Download files from url to local device in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In .Net 4.0 I used WebClient to download files from an url and save them on my local drive. But I am not able to achieve the same in .Net Core.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Are you sure asp.net-core-mvc is the right tag? From your question it seems you're talking about client software. Either way: Use `HttpClient` if you want to download files.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`WebClient` is not available in `.NET Core`. (UPDATE: It is from [2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netcore-2.2)) The usage of `HttpClient` in the `System.Net.Http` is therefore mandatory:

```c#
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
...
public static async Task<byte[]> DownloadFile(string url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {

        using (var result = await client.GetAsync(url))
        {
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            }

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: For readers, be aware that you shouldn't use HttpClient this way. An option is to let HttpClientFactory handle the lifetime of an Httpclient object. Read [more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912160/should-httpclient-instances-created-by-httpclientfactory-be-disposed)

Answer (score 24):

`WebClient` is available from [.net core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netcore-2.2)

```
var wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile( URL, @"c:\temp\myfile.txt");
```

Comment: Good to know, when you really want to download a file instead of using the content.

Comment: What happens if the remote file is not accessible, or the URL is wrong? Is there some way to know if the file was successfully downloaded or not?

Comment: @Stian It throws an exception

Comment: you should stop using webclient.

Comment: @Leandro: why?.

Comment: To begin, is not async. There is a lot of information about it, for e.g. this post is 6 yo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient

Comment: You have the `DownloadFileAsync` method (this is .net core)

Answer (score 8):

In **NetCore 6.0**, you should use `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient` which is obsolete, and you have the async methods in the new `File` class.

**The implementation is simple as the following:**

```
static async Task DownloadFile(string url, string pathToSave, string fileName)
{
    var content = await GetUrlContent(url);
    if (content != null)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(pathToSave)) Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToSave);
        await File.WriteAllBytesAsync($"{pathToSave}/{fileName}", content);
    }
}

static async Task<byte[]?> GetUrlContent(string url)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var result = await client.GetAsync(url))
        return result.IsSuccessStatusCode ? await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync():null;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
await DownloadFile("https://exampl.com/image.jpg", @"c:\DownloadedImages", "image.jpg");
```

Comment: This answer is nearly perfect, however it's generally not considered best practice to instantiate HttpClient using the constructor directly unless you are certain you will only do this once in the application lifetime. Better to construct a singleton to be reused or use IHttpClientFactory (personal favorite). More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/httpclient-guidelines