# Should HttpClient instances created by HttpClientFactory be disposed?

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, idisposable, asp.net-core-2.1, httpclientfactory

So, I've registered a named client with the services collection in my Startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient(someServiceName, 
                       client => client.BaseAddress = baseAddress);
```

and now can inject an `IHttpClientFactory` from my service provider.

Using this `IHttpClientFactory`, I conjure up a client instance:

```cs
var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(someServiceName)
```

Once upon a time, it was necessary to be very careful about the disposing of `HttpClient` instances, as it was [rarely the right thing to do](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/).

However, now we have `HttpClientFactory`, does this matter any more? Should/Can this `client` be disposed without worry? e.g.

```cs
using (var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(someServiceName))
using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(somePath, someData))
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SomeResponse>();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Check this article which explains how client is handled by factory https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, I've read that. However, I've located some code that looks much like the last snippet in my question, and I'm wondering if I need to fix it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Calling the `Dispose` method is not required but you can still call it if you need for some reasons.

Proof: [HttpClient and lifetime management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#httpclient-and-lifetime-management)

> Disposal of the client isn't required. Disposal cancels outgoing requests and guarantees the given HttpClient instance can't be used after calling Dispose. IHttpClientFactory tracks and disposes resources used by HttpClient instances. The HttpClient instances can generally be treated as .NET objects not requiring disposal.

Let's check the [source of `DefaultHttpClientFactory`](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs):

```cs
public HttpClient CreateClient(string name)
{
    if (name == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
    }

    var handler = CreateHandler(name);
    var client = new HttpClient(handler, disposeHandler: false);

    var options = _optionsMonitor.Get(name);
    for (var i = 0; i < options.HttpClientActions.Count; i++)
    {
        options.HttpClientActions[i](client);
    }

    return client;
}
```

The instance of `HttpMessageHandler` stores unmanaged resources of the `HttpClient`. In the classical scenario the `HttpClient` creates the instance of `HttpMessageHandler` and disposes it while itself disposing.

You can see in the above code that different instances of `HttpClient` shares single instance of `HttpMessageHandler` and doesn't dispose it (`disposeHandler: false`).

So, the call of the `HttpClient.Dispose` does nothing. But it's not dangerous.

Answer (score 42):

No. You should not dispose of your client. To be more general, you should not dispose of *anything* retrieved via a DI container, which in ASP.NET Core is by default the service collection. The lifetime is managed by the DI container, so if you dispose of the client, but it's later injected into something, you'll get an `ObjectDisposedException`. Let the container handle disposal.

This is actually a common confusion with `IDisposable` classes. You should personally only implement `IDisposable` if your class itself owns dependencies. If all its dependencies are *injected*, you should not implement `IDisposable`, since it doesn't own anything that needs disposal. Likewise, you should not dispose of anything injected into your class, as it doesn't own those dependencies. Only dispose of things you specifically new up. If you don't see the keyword `new`, you probably shouldn't be disposing.

Comment: Well this is a little confusing, because the client *isn't* retrieved via a DI container.  The *factory* is retrieved via a DI container.

Comment: And the factory owns the clients and disposes of them. When the factory is disposed, it will dispose of any clients it owns. The same rule still applies: if you don't explicitly new it up, don't dispose it.

Comment: but the naming in httpClientFactory.CreateClient(someServiceName) does seem to imply that you new it up, so that is the confusing part. I'm with @KierenJohnstone

Comment: It's doesn't matter that a resource is newed up, only whether or not you control its lifetime. In the case of the factory, the factory does the instantiation and it controls the lifetime, not you. That's the point. Only dispose of resources that belong to you.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Would you agree this would be less of a problem if C# or .NET included some kind of semantics for object lifetime and ownership to prevent this kind of confusion? Even something simple like an interface (e.g. `IDisposableHahahNotReally`) or referring to objects by a smart-pointer-type object, e.g. `OwnedObject<T>.Instance` and `BorrowedObject<T>.Value`).

Comment: Not really. It's very straight forward actually. Unless you use `new` you don't dispose. Calling a factory's create method is not the same. There, the factory is newing stuff up, so it is responsible for disposing, not you. And, of course, if you're injecting, you obviously don't dispose.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I don't think it matters. I remember reading in a GitHub issue on the ASP.NET repo that it is the HttpClientHandler that must not be disposed. When you dispose of a HttpClient (created by a factory as above) the handler "tells" the clients not to dispose of it, when it gets disposed of. So, code like this is not problematic at all `using (var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient())`. (I think) :)

Comment: Perhaps not. I know that HttpMessageHandler is what the factory actually holds on to and the HttpClient instances are transient scoped. However, the simple fact remains that you shouldn't dispose of that which you don't create or own. If the implementation were to change, you might suddenly break something.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, this is such a leaky abstraction.  HttpClient dispose cancels pending requests.  So we should know that and cancel pending requests manually if needed because we're now responsible for knowing what Dispose does when we created HttpClients outside of the factory class?

Comment: @Dai Dispose pattern isn't about lifetime management.  It's about resource management.  This thread conflates the two.  By it's definition Dispose should be idempotent.  Calling it multiple times should never break anything.

Comment: It's a nice rule of thumb that I shouldn't need to dispose of anything created by a factory. But as far as I can tell I have to break that rule immediately when I use a `ServiceScopeFactory` or a `DbContextFactory`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party I suppose, but I was looking at the [Microsoft learn stuff here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory), and there was a code sample that caught my eye:

```
public sealed class TodoService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory = null!;
    private readonly ILogger<TodoService> _logger = null!;

    public TodoService(
        IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory,
        ILogger<TodoService> logger) =>
        (_httpClientFactory, _logger) = (httpClientFactory, logger);

    public async Task<Todo[]> GetUserTodosAsync(int userId)
    {
        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        //                                        //
        // HERE IT IS - USING WITH THE HTTP CLIENT//
        //                                        //
        ////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Create the client
        using HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    
        try
        {
            // Make HTTP GET request
            // Parse JSON response deserialize into Todo types
            Todo[]? todos = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Todo[]>(
                $"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?userId={userId}",
                new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web));

        return todos ?? Array.Empty<Todo>();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError("Error getting something fun to say: {Error}", ex);
    }

    return Array.Empty<Todo>();
}
```

}

I'd be interested to see others' thoughts on this.