# Azure Function / API Socket Exception

Tags: c#, azure, sockets, .net-core, httpclientfactory

We have Azure function hosted on premium plan and we intermittently getting **System.Net.Sockets.SocketException** with below error message while calling our On Premise API -

**An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.. An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.**

Function is in .net core 3.1 and we use httpclientfactory to get httpclient... We don't set timeout value so default should be 100 seconds. We see the connection is time out after 120 seconds based on the network capture.

**This is happening from Azure App Services (.net core Web API) as well which are in .NET core 3.1 and uses the same way of using httpclient.**

```
using (var httpClient = this.httpClientFactory.CreateClient())
```

Please let me know if anyone has thoughts what could be causing. We have verified that On Premise API works fine when they are called from other On Premise API and don't see any error.  I am not thinking that this will be an issue on httpclient side rather network issue between Azure Services / On Premise API but I might be wrong so thought of checking with you guys.

Below is the stack trace-

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+d__53.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+<SendWithNtConnectionAuthAsync>d__48.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a) at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool+d__47.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler+<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a) at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler+d__2.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
Inner exception System.IO.IOException handled at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+d__53.MoveNext:
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException (System.Net.Sockets, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult (System.Net.Sockets, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream+<g__InternalFillBufferAsync|215_0>d`1.MoveNext (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a) at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Net.Security.SslStream+<ReadAsyncInternal>d__214`1.MoveNext (System.Net.Security, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+d__87.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+d__84.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection+d__53.MoveNext (System.Net.Http, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
Inner exception System.Net.Sockets.SocketException handled at System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException:

Comment: Side Note: You [should not dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50912303/1204153) of `HttpClient`s returned from `IHttpClientFactory`.

Comment: *We see the connection is time out after 120 seconds based on the network capture.* if your connections are lasting longer than a few seconds, your server will have socket starvation issues. You need to figure out why the remove server is holding on to connections for so long. Chances are it's bogged down with requests and can't keep up.

Comment: It might not be it, but in the scenario you describe you should at least be aware of [SNAT port exhaustion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/troubleshoot-outbound-connection). The Diagnose and Solve Problems section in the Azure Portal is quite good for identifying this.

Comment: Thanks @Andy yeah it make sense, it happens when there are huge number of requests....I read the link you gave on dispose httpclient and will read further on the same.

Comment: I guess only question we have is why that happening from Azure only.... what is the limit of sockets Azure can open...

Comment: Our On Premise Server has idle time out set to 120 seconds so I guess based on comment from Andy looks like servers are holding up connections for long... whats the best way to troubleshoot this issue..any tool

Answer (score 0):

The only possible solution is to scale up your plan. Seems that you've reached the max tcp connections for the selected app service plan. You can find the limits in the following link:

[https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/03/01/Deep-Dive-into-TCP-Connections-in-App-Service-Diagnostics.html#:~:text=ddd.%E2%80%9D%20The%20maximum%20connection%20limits,per%20B3%2FS3%2FP3%20instance](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/03/01/Deep-Dive-into-TCP-Connections-in-App-Service-Diagnostics.html#:%7E:text=ddd.%E2%80%9D%20The%20maximum%20connection%20limits,per%20B3%2FS3%2FP3%20instance)