# Microsoft Cognitive Face API Person Group Create Error

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I'm trying to create a person-group using MS Cognitive face API but I keep getting the error message "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.". Below is my source code. Would be glad if anybody could help me solve this.

```
using (var q3 = new WebClient())
{
    q3.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
    q3.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
    string url = "https://eastus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/persongroups/identificationapp2";
    string json = "{\"name\":\"" + "TEST" + "\", \"userData\":\"" + "TEST INFORMATION" + "\" }";
    string str = q3.UploadString(url, json);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for your region for this `Create PersonGroup` method [here](https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395244), you must do a `PUT` operation:

[image: API description]

In your code you are doing the following:

```
string str = q3.UploadString(url, json);
```

Which is doing a `POST`, not a `PUT` (see doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadstring?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365&view=netframework-4.7.2)). To do a `PUT`, you can specify the method:

```
string str = q3.UploadString(url, "PUT", json);
```

PS: you can also use `HttpClient`, see why [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient)

Comment: Nicolas, It worked correctly, thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Great. If that was helpful please don't hesitate to accept my answer