# WebClient not following redirect in .net Core 3.0

Tags: .net, .net-core

In .net 4.7.2 we can use WebClient to download a file from a server that redirects to another server. The file is actually hosted in the second server, i.e: Amazon S3 or any Cloud storage.

In .net Core, however WebClient would return status 302 for the same scenario. We could use HttpClient to get the AbsoluteUri of the redirected Url, and then point WebClient to the new Uri to fetch the file. But this is a workaround.

My question to .net Core contributors is: is there going to be a fix to WebClient in .net Core to go ahead and follow the redirect to fetch the file? Or, is this a setup by design to address some kind of security concerns?

Comment: Why not just use HttpClient?

Comment: Because we are interested in using the .DownloadFile function. Still, either way I'm getting 302 with .Net Core

Comment: "we are interested in using .DownloadFile" makes this sound like an XY question. you have already mentioned need (making a call) and the solution that will help you achieve it.

Comment: @Neville: the original question was, why webclient in .net core could not follow redirect, whereas webclient in .net framework would follow redirect with no problem. But then the discussion got sidetracked to why not use httpclient

Comment: Yes, you mentioned you are trying to get this with `WebClient`. That's what makes it an XY problem

Answer (score 1):

**HttpClient** can be considered a *"newer version"* of WebClient.

WebClient is available for compatibility purposes

[Help link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient)

Comment: it doesn't really matter HttpClient or WebClient. The main problem is, .Net Core is getting a 302 status code when the host redirects to a file server. Aside from the 302 status code, WebClient has .DownloadFile function whereas HttpClient doesn't

Comment: HttpClient acts this way because he does not now how to handle different HTTP codes or whether they should be handled at all. He just returns a response returned by server. Contrary to that WebClient tries to act "like a browser" in some scenarios. They are designed for a little bit different purposes and I dont think that using HttpClient is a workaround at all. It is more about having control over entire process.

Comment: For .net Core I believe it is, because there is no other way of getting the redirect URI without HttpClient. For regular .net Framework we don't need this redirect URI since WebClient would follow thru when redirected. So, when my app hits Endpoint A, and Endpoint A redirects to Endpoint B, WebClient can follow that path to EndPoint B. But only in .Net Framework. In .Net Core it would stop at A