# OData metadata url request fails if I set the version

Tags: c#, .net, odata, odatalib

The following code gets a 500:

```cs
WebRequest request =
  WebRequest.Create("https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/$metadata");
HttpWebRequest webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Accept = "application/atom+xml,application/xml";
request.Headers.Add("DataServiceVersion", "4.0");
request.Headers.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
webRequest.AutomaticDecompression =
  DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

// this throws the 500
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

But this succeeds:

```cs
WebRequest request =
   WebRequest.Create("https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/$metadata");
HttpWebRequest webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Accept = "application/atom+xml,application/xml";
request.Headers.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
webRequest.AutomaticDecompression =
  DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

This throws error:

```cs
WebRequest request = 
  WebRequest.Create("https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/Airlines");
HttpWebRequest webRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
webRequest.Accept = "application/atom+xml,application/xml";
request.Headers.Add("DataServiceVersion", "4.0");
request.Headers.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
webRequest.AutomaticDecompression =
  DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

// this throws the 500
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

Is there something special where I should not specify the DataServiceVersion when requesting the metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/understand-odata-in-6-steps/), the header for the OData-version, is `OData-Version`, not `DataServiceVersion`.

Based on my test using [Postman](https://postman.com), this is what was throwing the 500 error.

And BTW, consider using `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`, works asynchronously, and is lighter than `WebClient`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient) and [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/06/01/calling-web-services.aspx).

Comment: First, thank you. Did it used to be DataServiceVersion? I don't see how we would have had something wrong in there otherwise.

Comment: Yes David, that threw the 500 error. As soon as I removed or fixed this header it all worked well.

Comment: Yes, but is this new to version 4? Because in versions 2 & 3 I think it uses DataServiceVersion (and MaxDataServiceVersion)? thanks

Comment: That I don't know. It might have ignored those headers too without you knowing about it.