# POST Request with json in c#

Tags: c#, json, post

I am attempting to do a POST request which I have got working through Postman but I am getting a 400 error when done from code.

I am trying to reach the POST endpoint from here: http://developer.oanda.com/rest-live-v20/order-ep/

Here is my code, does anything look incorrect or have I missed anything?

```
public void MakeOrder(string UID)
    {
        string url = $"https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/{UID}/orders";
        string body = "{'order': {'units': '10000', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'timeInForce': 'FOK', 'type': 'MARKET', 'positionFill': 'DEFAULT'}}";
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer 11699873cb44ea6260ca3aa42d2898ac-2896712134c5924a25af3525d3bea9b0");
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            client.UploadString(url, body);
        }
    }
```

I'm very new to coding so apologies if it is something very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use HttpClient from System.Net.Http:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{

       string url = $"https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/{UID}/orders";
       string body = "{'order': {'units': '10000', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'timeInForce': 'FOK', 'type': 'MARKET', 'positionFill': 'DEFAULT'}}";
       var content = new StringContent(body , Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
       var result = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
       var contents = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately even with the Authorization header added im still getting a 400 error :/
Does string body look correct to you?

Comment: have you tried your json with " instead of ' ? sometimes little specification like this can has effects . don't forget you need to escape " in string as \"

Comment: Just tried it and unfortunately I still get the same error.
On the OANDA Api instruction it says the following parameter is needed in the Header - Accept-Datetime-Format, I did not have to input anything like that into Postman to get it to work, just the Authorization and application/json. Could it be anything to do with that do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `HttpClient` over WebClient. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient) the difference.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{

    string url = $"https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/{UID}/orders";
    string body = "{'order': {'units': '10000', 'instrument': 'EUR_USD', 'timeInForce': 'FOK', 'type': 'MARKET', 'positionFill': 'DEFAULT'}}";
    var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1OTIzMDY0NTQsImlzcyI6IlRlc3QuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiVGVzdC5jb20ifQ.c-3boD5NtOEhXNUnzPHGD4rY1lbEd-pjfn7C6kDPbxw");
    var result = httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).Result;
    var contents = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Using this I still seem to be getting the 400 Error - Bad Request.

Comment: I have tested the code with my API, its working fine with my API. so I think there is some issue with the data your are posting.

Comment: Could you please show me the postman? what data your are sending and header as well

Comment: 2 Custom Headers:
Authorization: Bearer 11699873cb44ea6260ca3aa42d2898ac-2896712134c5924a25af3525d3bea9b0
Content-Type: application/json

Body: {
 "order": {
  "units": "100",
  "instrument": "EUR_USD",
  "timeInForce": "FOK",
  "type": "MARKET",
  "positionFill": "DEFAULT"
 }
}

Comment: only one header? no content type?

Comment: Yes, it is there after the api key. Sorry the comment layout isnt very easy on the eye

Comment: Could it be the body string? Does it look correct in the way I have format it?

Comment: Haha I've posted the answer 3 hours ago and I forgot only to include API Key header and wow such a good community is here !

Comment: @MahyarPasarzangene you missed the main part, which can cause the issue