# How to call a Put on WebApi Method using C#

Tags: c#

I've developed a WebApi Put Method :

```
 [Route("api/woo/setOrderStatusComplete")]
    [HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage SetOrderStatus(string country, string orderNo)
```

which expects to be called in the form:

```
http://<myWebAddress>/WooService/api/woo/setOrderStatus?country=uk&orderNo=23662
```

I've tested my endpoint from swagger and all works fine, However, I'm having difficulty writing a code sample to call my endpoint from other C# Apps that will call this end point. Can anyone point me to an example.

As a starter for 10 I'm using :

```
HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
webrequest.Method = "PUT";
webrequest.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Comment: There are lots of ways in c# to make the API request.  Which one are you using?  That's the only way we can help you figure out which technique for setting the HTTP method is appropriate.

Comment: @KirkWoll I've amended the question to include my stat point

Comment: Can you elaborate on your *"difficulty"*? Is there an error? Undesired behavior?

Comment: @Crowcoder theApi itself works I now need to provide an example of calling the 'PUT' method from outside the Api so that other developers know how to call it.

Comment: @bilpor  Please do not use WebRequest, WebClient to make API calls since they are marked as obsolete: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated . Please use the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` class instead.

Comment: @RahulSharma Most of the Apps that will be using this endpoint are .Net 4.7.2. They are a not in a position to upgrade their apps to .NET Core, so I need to provide an example in the earlier stuff

Comment: @bilpor Maybe this will change your mind: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23959136/1807452

Comment: @RahulSharma so  for .net 4.7.2, I can tell developers to call my method in the following form: ` private static HttpResponseMessage CallRestPutMethod(string Url)
        {
            

            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Url);
            var responseTask = httpClient.PutAsync(Url, null);
            responseTask.Wait();

            return responseTask.Result;
        }`

Comment: @bilpor don't create a [new HttpClient for each request](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and do not [block async calls](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), especially in .NET Framework.